# Radio button value is not null

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I'm making a website with a wizard-like web form, split up in multiple `fieldset`. Because of this, the `required` attribute for `input` doesn't work until you reach the last slide, where the complete form is submitted. However, since only the current `fieldset` is visible, you won't get an alert if you forgot to fill in a `required` in an earlier `fieldset`.

This is why I'm trying to implement some jQuery that checks the value of an `input` that has the attribute `required`, so a user doesn't end up on page 8 and tries to submit the form, without knowing he/she forgot to fill in a `required` on page 2.

The problem I'm having is with a `radio` input. I know I only have to add one `required` to the whole list for the attribute to work in HTML, but since my jQuery checks the value of `[required]`, it doesn't matter what radio-button I select, the value will always be the one I added required to.

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/mepLaorr/1/)

**Here's some HTML**

```
<div class="description">
    Pladstype:
</div>
<div class="descriptionData">
    <select id="form_billet_pladstype" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Vælg pladstype</option>
        <option value="0">Ståpladser</option>
        <option value="1">Siddepladser</option>
        <option value="2">Sidde- og ståpladser</option>
    </select>
</div>

<div class="description">
    Nummererede pladser:
</div>
<div class="descriptionData">
    <div class="descriptionData">
        <input required type="radio" value="ja" name="form_billet_nummererede" id="form_billet_nummererede_ja" class="descriptionData janej valid"><label for="form_billet_nummererede_ja">Ja</label>
        <input type="radio" value="nej" name="form_billet_nummererede" id="form_billet_nummererede_nej" class="descriptionData janej valid"><label for="form_billet_nummererede_nej">Nej</label>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="description">
    Billet-nr.:
</div>
<div class="descriptionData">
    <select name="form_ticketType" id="form_ticketType" required>
        <option value="" disabled selected>Vælg billetnr.</option>
        <option value="0">Type 0 - Unummereret plads</option>
        <option value="14">Type 14 - Unummererede m. niveau, række og plads</option>
        <option value="15">Type 15 - Alle felter</option>
    </select>
</div/>
```

**The jQuery**

```
var requiredFields = $(element).find('#' + stepName + ' [required]')
requiredFields.each( function(idx, elem) {
    var val = $(elem).val();
    alert(val);
});
```

I understand now, after writing this question, that the value for the `radio` is always the one on which I've added `required`, but how do I fix this, so it actually has a value of `null` when the page is loaded and just gets a value of `checked` (or the real value, but not necessary) when one of the options is selected?

The easy way out would be to have one box selected on load, after which he can choose the other one, but I'm wondering if it's possible to start with an empty value for the radio-input, but still use `required`.

Comment: Should a space be between `id` and  `[required]` at `'#' + stepName + ' [required]'` ?

Comment: Yes, because it needs to get all `[required]` from the currently visible `fieldset` (targeted with `'#' + stepName`)

Comment: Not certain interpret requirement correctly ? Set `input required` to `true` when an `option` is selected ?

Comment: I don't think you understand what `required` does in this situation, @guest271314...

Comment: Prevent `form` submission ?

Comment: Yes, but your comment doesn't make sense. Also, comments are not a chat. If you know a possible solution, please write it as an answer.

Comment: You are correct, do not understand requirement, here. Attempting to gather at comments. Can create stacksnippets to demonstrate ?

Comment: I actually had a Fiddle, which I forgot to add. https://jsfiddle.net/mepLaorr/1/
Summary: I want to check if inputs with `required` have been filled in, before a user can continue to the next `fieldset`. However, when you add `required` to a `radio`, it'll always have a value, selected or not.

Comment: What is purpose of setting `value` at `input type="radio"` at `html` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the problem by adding an extra, hidden `radio`-button. This radio-button has the attribute `required`, so if neither Yes or No is chosen, HTML will still see these radio-buttons as empty.

Since the value of the hidden radio-button is `null`, the code that'll check if a value is not null will register that as empty.

I've added a few more lines of jQuery, which remove the `required` from the hidden radio-button and add it to the selected one, so I actually get the value of the selected one (even though that's not really necessary, just knowing something is selected is enough).

```
$('#form_billet_nummererede_ja').bind('click', function(e) {
    $('#form_billet_nummererede_hidden').removeAttr('required');
    $('#form_billet_nummererede_ja').attr('required', true);
})

$('#form_billet_nummererede_nej').bind('click', function(e) {
    $('#form_billet_nummererede_hidden').removeAttr('required');
    $('#form_billet_nummererede_nej').attr('required', true);
})
```

[Updated fiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/mepLaorr/3/)

Answer (score -1):

```
var requiredFields = $(element).find('#' + stepName + ':required')
```

This would be your solution.

Comment: `[required]` or `:required` are basically the same. Check my updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mepLaorr/2/